# Magento2: Css loading issue on admin login page

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, css

On the Admin Login css/js is not loading, I don't have this problem anywhere else on my site.
How can i solve this?
I did

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> bin/magento, bin/magento setup:upgrade

cleared my cache multiple times but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Try `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then `systemctl reload apache2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, for some reason the js/css was linked to the 'en_GB' store instead of en_US.

Because of this the css didn't load, you can change it in the database core_config data, set general/locale/code to the preferred store.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the **apache2.conf** file.

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Navigate to the place in the apache2.conf file.Change **"AllowOverride None"** to **"AllowOverride All"** Save the file.

Enabled mod_rewrite:

> sudo a2enmod rewrite
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, "AllowOverride All" has already been set, any other ideas?

Comment: check permission for /pub/static/adminhtml , /pub/static/frontend also check /var/cache , /var/view_preprocessed

Comment: Found the issue, for some reason the css/js was linked to the en_GB store instead of en_US